# what is wrong with my query, it is not being saved?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am migrating an app from old apex to the new version. some of my pages are not saving the new changes that I am making. for example this is my query for a page item from the old apex environment:

```sql
select DESCRIPTION display_value, DESCRIPTION return_value 
from AUC_AUCTION_TB
where admin_emailaddress =
    (select email
     from SYSTEM_USERNAME_TB
     where username = :APP_USER) or :APP_USER in ('SESH','PETS','ROPO','JEMU','HESH')
order by START_DATE desc
```

So I want to make some changes to the query in the new environment, because the new environment is using a different table. My new query is:

```sql
select DESCRIPTION display_value, DESCRIPTION return_value 
from AUC_AUCTION_TB
where admin_emailaddress = 
    (select EMAIL
     from ALL_USERS
     where USERNAME = :APP_USER) or
         :APP_USER in ('SESH','tshithigonap','poolmar','muhulumaj','shipaleh')
order by START_DATE desc
```

The problem is when I make this changes the page is not being saved with the new changes, I keep getting this pop up:

> There are unsaved changes. Press Ok to discard your changes or Cancel to return to the current page.

So when I go to a different page and then come back to my page, I notice non of my changes have been saved, even though I clicked the save button. Is something wrong with my query perhaps or why is this happening, I have many pages with this issue, please help.

Comment: Execute the new query manually in a worksheet in sqlmodeler (or whatever tool you are using) to see if it works.

Comment: I have tested the query in a different worksheet and it works, but when I put the same query in my page it is not being saved, and no error is given, what else could be the problem?

Comment: Hi Misha - If you refresh the page and try to make the changes again, does it work?
Which APEX version are you working on now?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to refresh the page, but it is still not accepting my changes and it doesn't give me an error, I don't understand why my changes are not being saved. Currently I am using Application Express 5.1.4.00.08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my changes were not being saved because I did not have permission, so one of the admins in the app changed my permission from Developer to administrator, so I logged out and logged in again with administrative rights. So this allowed me to change changes for a while and later I experienced the same problem again, but this time all I had to do was change the browser from chrome to Firefox, now everything is working perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be that query (it looks OK); there's something else that is wrong on that page. What? Check errors, here:

[image]

That's a dummy error I just produced, just to illustrate the issue; you'll get some other message. Then click on each of those messages - Apex will take you to that very spot.

Comment: There are no errors I have even tested the query in a different worksheet and it is working , returning values. But when I insert the query in the page , the page is not running without saving the query.

Comment: No idea, then. There's something wrong - obviously, otherwise you wouldn't ask for help. Maybe Apex' *data dictionary* tables contain information you can't see. Perhaps you'd be better off creating a brand new page (and drop existing one).

Answer (score 0):

If the query in your example gets executed correctly in a separate worksheet, there's probably an issue in passing the bind variables or setting the correct type of region.

Maybe try using `v('APP_USER')` instead of `:APP_USER`.

Comment: This does not seem to make any difference, I have even recreated the page just incase something else was wrong with my page but nothing, even the new page I created with the same query is not being saved. what else could be the problem?